# AJAX ifModified как использовать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть такой код:

```js
function show()
{
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "info.php",
        ifModified: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(jsondata, status){
            if (status === "success") {
                $("#queue").css("display", "none");
                $("#queue").html(jsondata.queue);
                $("#queue").fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $("#queue").html(jsondata.queue);
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    show();
    setInterval('show()', 3000);
});
```

```html
<div id="queue"></div>
```

Необходимо чтобы при получении новой информации, происходило плавное появление, если же данные не изменились, то ничего не происходило. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: ну в принципе с клиентской стороны все сделано, нужно чтобы сервер отдавал запрос с нужным статусом если ничего не поменялось

Comment: @Grundy, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: что именно? ответ от сервера? зависит от сервера. Некоторые и так шлют нужный статус.

Comment: @Grundy как узнать что данные изменились?

Comment: Ну так зависит от данных же. если например запрашивается файл - то можно проверить дату изменения файла, если берутся данные из базу - можно проверить дату изменения данных

Comment: @Grundy если допустим из базы берется кол-во строк, которые могут меняться?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33619/discussion-between-grundy-and-xenk).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете просто сравнивать содержимое Html  с текущим, раз уж все равно получаете готовый html в ответ и только при наличии отличий делать анимацию.

Comment: можете привести маленький пример?